# AIX cifs hostname with underscore

Tags: aix, command, hostname, cifs

I am trying to type this comand but for some reason it takes the first and not the second version.
I have entered both the host names in the host file, FYI.

This command works (hostname **zq13c1**):

```
mkcifsmnt -f /aix_bk5 -d AIX -h zq13c1 -c 'aix_user' -p 'Cognizant123' -u 214 -g 204 -t rw
```

This command does not work (hostname **zq13c1_bk**):

```
mkcifsmnt -f /aix_bk5 -d AIX -h zq13c1_bk -c 'aix_user' -p 'Cognizant123' -u 214 -g 204 -t rw
```

Comment: Hostnames can't have underscores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname):

> The Internet standards (Request for Comments) for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in RFC 952, mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a hyphen, and must not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent specification (RFC 1123) permitted hostname labels to start with digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are permitted.

The underscore `_` is not a valid character in a hostname.

Comment: alrity thats what I was guessing as well... but is there anyother way?

Comment: Use a dash `-` instead?